# Magento 1.9 : Admin Edit Form with Left and Right Column?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform

=> **My Edit Form currently showing like below.**

[image: current_from]

But I want to show it Left and Right side,I don't want in bottom.

**=> For example like below :**

[image: needed_form]

What I need to do for that.?

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the code and edit the div or ID in css.

```
<style>
.div float:right !important;
</style>
```

You can put it in custom.css or try with inspect first.

Comment: I didn't understand @Chris Gudn.

Comment: Can you give me a link to your site where I can check this out, or what page are you currently trying to edit?